# Highstock use select instead of From/To

Tags: jquery, highcharts

In highstock, the range selector provides two inputboxes for the date selection.  Is it possible to use a select dropdown instead of the From/To inputboxes?

For example, i have the chart below:

[image: Chart]

I want to change it to:

[image: New chart]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately it is not possible, only what you can do is hide this inputs, and prepare your own inputs / selects, which will use setExtremes() function

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.events.setExtremes